# How to put a view generated slideshow as a page background?

Tags: blocks, theming

I need to create a homepage with a slideshow as a background. 
The slideshow shows images and texts. Similar to this one: [enter link description here](http://www.euroartsubastas.es/index.php)

What I've done:

1) I created a slideshow block with views

2) I put that block in the homepage

Now I spent some hours playing with css to put it in the background and making it fill the entire page. But with no results at all..

I'd like to know if is there module to make easier to accomplish this.

Comment: I'd say this is more of a general CSS question than to do with Drupal...basically look at making the slideshow appear first in the page markup, make it `position:absolute` and set height/width. Then change the z-index for the slideshow to something low, and the z-index for the main page content to something higher

Comment: you're right, maybe I didn't make the point of my question clear which is: **is there a module out there to do this?* Thanks for the css tips though.

Comment: Basically, you don`t need a module to do this (i don`t think it exists) - it`s a css question so far. The only thing to do is to locate your block or whatever and made things Clive said unto you )

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the [Backgroundfield module](http://drupal.org/project/backgroundfield) with [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). Create a View with display option Slideshow and the only field to display as your background field. Violá, no coding required.

Comment: Did Backgroundfield and Views Slideshow actually work for you? Just curious, I tried it and it didn't work on D7.

Comment: Yes, I have used it successfully on D7.

Comment: beth, I've installed Backgroundfield module together with Views Slideshow, but background is set only once, not when every slide changes. Do I need to set something or this is not working that way?

Comment: It might be a caching issue.